# Warning: Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (4.11) and test app (4.12)

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I'm trying to resolve two errors:

1. Cannot resolve symbol 'test'
2. Cannot resolve symbol 'AndroidJUnit4'

To run integration tests in my Android Studio project. To solve this, I've seen some answers and my build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ps.comunio.comuniops"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.0'
    compile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
}
```

This solve both errors, but a warning appears:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'junit:junit' in project ':app'.
>   Resolved versions for app (4.11) and test app (4.12) differ.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

One solution is to force Gradle to compile `junit:junit:4.11` instead of `junit:junit:4.12`

To do that, in your app's `build.gradle`, add the following:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'junit:junit:4.11'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
```

with

```
compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
```

[replace testCompile with compile]

Answer (score -1):

With your problem you can try:

```
file>>project Structure>>app>>dependencies>>click button "+" >>library dependence>>input junit>>click junit 4.12>>done
```

OK